# Get list items and push into array for jqBarGraph

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

Not sure what I'm missing below but would like to push some item lists into this array in this format below:

```
stackedByYear = new Array(
            [[14,44],'2007'],
            [[18,38],'2008'],
            [[4.5,22],'2009']        
        );
```

I tried the below but not working

```
var stackedByYear= function() {
 var listName = "Budget_Vs_Actual";
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;     
    getListItems(listName, url, function (data) {       
        var array = new Array();
        var items = data.d.results;              
        var html = "";
        // Add all the new items
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            //alert(items[i].Title + ":" + items[i].Actual + "" + items[i].Budget);
           //array.push(3,4,'wew');
          array.push([items[i].Actual,items[i].Budget,items[i].Title]);

        }
         return array;    
})
};
```

I would like to pass the array results to the below

```
$("#stackedGraph").jqBarGraph({

    data: stackedByYear,

    colors: ['#242424','#437346'],

    legends: ['ads','leads'],

    legend: true,

    width: 500,

    prefix: '$',

    postfix: 'k',

    title: '<h3>Total revenue by year <br /><small>stacked bar graph</small></h3>'

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the body of your for loop to this (notice the double `[` ):

```
array.push([[items[i].Actual,items[i].Budget],items[i].Title]);
```

Comment: Thanks for that but when i call the stackedByYear in the  data: stackedByYear it doesn't work .Do you know what i could be missing?